# Adding a further constraint to the Timefold timetabling example where teachers can only work certain days

Tags: java, optimization, timefold

I am trying to extend the Timefold 'Hello World' java example. I have added in my own lesson, class and teacher data, and now I want to add in an additional constraint, where certain teachers only work on certain days.

I have tried this:

```
Constraint restDayConstraint(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        // teachers don't teach on their rest day
        return constraintFactory
                .forEachUniquePair(Lesson.class, Teacher.class,
                        Joiners.equal(Lesson::getTimeslot),
                        Joiners.equal(Teacher::getTeacher))
                .filter((lesson1, teacher) -> lesson1.getTimeslot().getDayOfWeek() != teacher.getRestDay())
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                .justifyWith(
                        (lesson1, teacher, score) -> new TeacherConflictJustification(lesson1.getTeacher(), lesson1, teacher))
                .asConstraint("Teacher conflict");
    }
```

and have created a Teacher.java file with the following code:

```
package org.acme.schooltimetabling.domain;

import ai.timefold.solver.core.api.domain.entity.PlanningEntity;
import ai.timefold.solver.core.api.domain.lookup.PlanningId;
import ai.timefold.solver.core.api.domain.variable.PlanningVariable;

@PlanningEntity
public class Teacher {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    private String subject;
    private String restDay;

    @PlanningVariable
    private Timeslot timeslot;

    @PlanningVariable
    private Room room;

    // No-arg constructor required for Timefold
    public Teacher() {
    }

    public Teacher(long id, String subject, String restDay) {
        this.id = id;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.restDay = restDay;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return subject + "(" + id + ")";
    }

    // ************************************************************************
    // Getters and setters
    // ************************************************************************

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getRestDay() {
        return restDay;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

}
```

But I get the following error:

```
The method forEachUniquePair(Class<A>, BiJoiner<A,A>, BiJoiner<A,A>) in the type ConstraintFactory is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Lesson>, BiJoiner<Lesson,Lesson>, BiJoiner<Teacher,Teacher>)
```

How can I enforce the constraint that certain teachers only work on certain days?

Answer (score 0):

I think that error is caused by the fact that you are trying to perform a forEachUniquePair() method on 2 different entities (Teacher, Lesson) while the  method is designed for a single Planning entity (Lesson or Teacher).
https://javadoc.io/doc/ai.timefold.solver/timefold-solver-core-impl/latest/ai/timefold/solver/core/api/score/stream/ConstraintFactory.html#forEachUniquePair(java.lang.Class,ai.timefold.solver.core.api.score.stream.bi.BiJoiner,ai.timefold.solver.core.api.score.stream.bi.BiJoiner)
I don't know why did you choose to have 2 Planning Entities. Maybe you can tell me more about what you are trying to achieve.

You can refer to this documentation if you want to understand better the difference between Planning Entities, Planning Variables and Problem Facts: https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/using-timefold-solver/modeling-planning-problems#problemFact

I would advise you to model your domain as in this example: https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/technology/java-spring-boot/src/main/java/org/acme/schooltimetabling/domain.

You can model your Lesson and Teacher classes like this:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Lesson {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    private String subject;
    private Teacher teacher;
    private String studentGroup;

    @JsonIdentityReference
    @PlanningVariable
    private Timeslot timeslot;

    @JsonIdentityReference
    @PlanningVariable
    private Room room;

    //constructors and getters and setters

public class Teacher {

    private Long id;
    private String subject;
    private List<DayOfWeek> restDay;

    //contructors and getters and setters
```

Then I would model the constraint as it follows:

```
Constraint restDayConstraint(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        // teachers don't teach on their rest day
        return constraintFactory
                .forEachUniquePair(Lesson.class,
                        Joiners.equal(Lesson::getTimeslot),
                        Joiners.equal((lesson) -> lesson.getTeacher()))
                .filter((lesson1, teacher) -> 
// check if the teacher's restDays contains the day of the lesson
teacher.getRestDay().contains(lesson1.getTimeslot().getDayOfWeek()))
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                .justifyWith(
                        (lesson1, teacher, score) -> new TeacherConflictJustification(lesson1.getTeacher(), lesson1, teacher))
                .asConstraint("Teacher conflict");
    }
```

This is how I would solve the problem. Let me know if it helped.